# How do I remove background / gradient styling from jquery mobile listviews

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, themeroller

I'm trying to override the standard styling of a listview li element in jquery mobile. I tried just setting a rule at the end of all the css

```
li{
background-color:#ffffff;
border:none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

But there are still some styles being applied. I just want a solid background color and no gradient stuff.

Comment: If there are any rules regarding these elements with a class/id, such as `li.listview` or `#listview li`, they will override `li`. See [this](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
li{
background:#ffffff !important;
border:none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
```

This will override the gradient colors created by jQuery Mobile using `background-image` style

Comment: WARNING: This will set the color for all themes, in all states (selected and hover as well).

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your code...

```
background-image:url('ANYNONEXISTINGIMAGE');
```

so, your code would look like this...

```
li{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    background-image:url('ANYNONEXISTINGIMAGE');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove all gradients from the list elements and don't want to overwrite colors, add this line to your `li` style:

```
background-image: none !important;
```